# Angular keeps saying Property or Signature is expected. How could I fix that?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

To start. I have **no access to the data, It's and API**. So I can't explicitly change the label.

I am trying to use some type declarations in angular for data being pulled from an API. Angular keeps throwing an error **Property or signature expected.ts(1131)** .

I have figured how to fix the error  it is as simple as adding a name to the object. The problem wit that is, the data does not comeback from the API labeled in that manner. How should I address this ?

This is the data

It has an array with 2 distinct objects. The object though are not labeled.

```
{
    "generated_at": "-",
    "schema": "-",
    "event": {
        "id": "-",
        "scheduled": "-",
        "value": false,
        "timing": {
            "type": "-",
        },
        "season": {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "start_date": "-",
            "end_date": "-",
            "year": "-",
        },
        "cycle": {
            "id": "",
            "name": "-",
            "car": {
                "id": "-",
                "name": "-"
            },
            "category": {
                "id": "-",
                "name": "-"
            },
            "type": "-",
            "value": "-"
        },
        "useful": [{
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "value": "-",
            "value2": "-",
            "value3": "-",
            "value4": "-"
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "value1": "-",
            "value2": "-",
            "value3": "-",
            "value4": "-"
        }],
        "venue": {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "city_name": "-",
            "country_name": "-",
            "map_coordinates": "--",
            "country_code": "-",
            "values": [{
                "name": "-"
            }, {
                "name": "-"
            }]
        }
    },
    "section": [{
        "locale": "-",
        "value": {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "country_code": "-"
        },
        "street_group": [{
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "locale": "-",
        "value": {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "country_code": "-"
        },
        "street_group": [
{
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, 
{
            "data": "-",
            "data": "-",
            "data": "-",
        }
        ]
}]
}
```

This is the Component

```
export class LiveComponent implements OnInit {
 allData: {
    generated_at: string;
    section: {
      street_group: { {name: string},
{data: string }
 }[];
      locale: string }[];
    event: {
      id: string;
      useful: { name: string }[];
    };
  }[] | null = null;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient ) {
    }
    ngOnInit(){
this.http.get('http://api.redacted_for_privacy').subscribe(data => {this.allData = [data as any];});
    }
    }
```

The issue occurs at

```
section: {
      street_group: { {name: string},
{data: string }
 }[];
```

On the second object.

How could I fix this. I do not have control of the data so i can't change the label.

I have tried adding my own label/declaration to those objects. The issue gets fixed but The code is  not usable since the data does not contain a specific reference to that label.

Help.